# Python subprocess.run() not responding on PySimpleGUI

Tags: python

When I run the sample code below and click on the button, the GUI window shows not responding? Maybe because The GUI is waiting for the subprocess.run() to finish, because when I close the browser that is opened by the GUI, it is not responding anymore. How can I use the GUI when using subprocess.run()? Thanks.
Here is my sample code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import subprocess

layout = [
     [sg.Button('Open Browser', key="ob")]
]

window = sg.Window('Metamask Accounts Opener', layout, element_justification='c', size=(400, 400))

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':  # if user closes window or clicks cancel
        break

    if event == "ob":
        subprocess.run('"C:/Program Files/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Application/brave.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9222 -- "%1"')

window.close()
```

Comment: Maybe take a look at the "Exec APIs" offered by PySimpleGUI to help you with subprocessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subprocess.run` waits for the process to finish. You need to use `Popen` in order to not wait and just run in the background.

```py
Popen(['"C:/Program Files/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Application/brave.exe"' ,"--remote-debugging-port=9222","--","%1"])
```